# Bash: Iterating through files with placeholder

Tags: bash, loops

I want to delete some directories that contain mounted (--bind) subdirs. I use following for loop in a script file named `.du` .

```
for dirname in $1; do                                                                                                                                         
    sudo umount $dirname/images/Spielplatz
    sudo umount $dirname/sounds/Spielplatz
    sudo rm -r $dirname
done
```

I call the script file with

```
.du Test*
```

to delete all directories that begin with "Test". But it only deletes the first one. So I have to call `.du` for every directory.

How do I have to write it, so that it processes all of them with one call?

Comment: @WalterA, absolutely not `in $*` -- that'll break horrifically if you have whitespace in your names.

Comment: BTW, you've got other bugs here as well. `rm -r $dirname` is not going to behave the way you want with all possible names. Make it `umount "$dirname/images/Spielplatz"` and `rm -r -- "$dirname"` -- with the quotes -- for reliability, and consider running your scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ to catch that kind of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UNIX, unlike DOS/Windows, glob expressions are expanded **before** a program starts. Thus:

```
.du Test*
```

runs something like `.du Test1 Test2 Test3` (if those are the files that match the glob). Thus, `$1` refers to `Test1`, whereas `$2` would be `Test2`, etc. The program has no way of knowing that it was originally invoked with `Test*` on the command line; all it's given is the post-expansion array.

To iterate over all elements in this array, use:

```
for dirname in "$@"; do
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doing exactly what you are asking for -- `$1` is the first argument.  To loop over all arguments, use `"$@"`:

```
for dirname in "$@"; do
```

You are even allowed to leave this out because it's the default;

```
for dirname; do
```